# BCP Format file to bulk import in SQL Server throws ODBC error

Tags: sql-server, bcp

When I execute the below `bcp` command to import data from a `.csv` file into my table in SQL Server, I get an ODBC error.

Here is the command:

```
DECLARE @Error INT

EXEC @Error = master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp DB.dbo.tbl_CASHBAL IN "H:\Imports\CASH BAL.csv" -f H:\CASHBAL.fmt -S myserver -U user -P xxxx'

SELECT @Error
```

Here is the table structure in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [UBS].[dbo].tbl_BilotherCASHBALN 
(
    [DATE] VARCHAR(100),
    [SCODE] VARCHAR(100),
    [MY-ACC-N] VARCHAR(100),
    [YOUR-ACC-N] VARCHAR(100),
    [CASH-BAL] VARCHAR(100)
)
```

This is my format file:

```
12.0
5
1       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     1     DATE                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     2     SCODE               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     3     MY-ACC-N              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"     4     YOUR-ACC-N              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\r\n"   5     CASH-BAL             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And this is the error I get when I execute my `bcp` command:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
> Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data file

I have included a screenshot of the complete error message here:

[image: ODBC error].

And here is one row of data from the `.csv` file (which I need in the SQL Server table without double quotes):

```
"2021-01-30","IX","0001234567","XYZ01234","2305123.19"
```

Comment: Your file says separators are tabulators but in the file you have commas?

Comment: By the way, why are you running this from SQL with `xp_cmdshell` give its security risks, just run it from an actual batch, or a Powershell SQL Agent job.

Comment: Jamez Z, what would be the proper way to set up my format file so that my data ends up without commas and I get no error while running my bcp command?

Comment: bcp.exe doesn't really work with Quoted CSV files. You'll need to transform them to Unquoted CSV files (and correct your `"\t"` field terminators to `","`) or use a different technique to read your data in, such as PowerShell scripts using `Import-Csv` to read the data.

Comment: just manually modify the format file to specify that the delimiter is not "\t" (which is a tab). bcp is looking for the first tab to find the first field of data and never finds it... so it tries to load all of the data into a single column and finds the end of your file before it finds a single tab. that is what your error means.

Comment: AlwaysLearning is somewhat correct. BCP does not handle quoted characters very gracefully, but it can if you really need it to. When encountering quoted string data, I usually opt for an SSIS package to load. Loading a quoted file can be done with BCP however. if you really need to use BCP, i can share an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure this out. I simply needed to modify the format file by adding one 'space' as the field terminator of my last column. I had not noticed that there was a space after my last column, and that there was a space after every last item in each row. Also, I needed to add one extra column in my format file that has double quote as the delimiter, and for this I set the column number to 0, so it is not imported. The final format file with proper field terminators looks like this:

```
    8.0
    6
    1       SQLCHAR             0       1    "\""         0   Unwanted         ""
    1       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\",\""     1     DATE                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    2       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\",\""     2     SCODE               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    3       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\",\""     3     MY-ACC-N              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    4       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\",\""     4     YOUR-ACC-N              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    5       SQLCHAR             0       100     "\" "   5     CASH-BAL             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

And the execution line within SQL Server Management Studio looks like this (I added F 2 to skip the header:)

```
    DECLARE @Error INT
    EXEC @Error = master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp DB.dbo.tbl_CASHBAL IN "H:\Imports\CASH BAL.csv" -f H:\CASHBAL.fmt -F 2 -S myserver -U user -P xxxx'
```

SELECT @Error